# Separate column in dataframe on the last space delimiter

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, stringr

Have the following dataframe

```
df = data.frame(Metric = c("Profit before tax 240", "Earnings per share 0.240" , "EBITDA Margin 37%"), Values =c(5, 1, 3))
```

gives

```
Metric                         Values
Profit before tax 240           5
Earnings per share 0.240        1
EBITDA Margin 37%               3
```

I have tried to split with the `stringr` package `str_split_fixed(df$Metric, " ", 3)` and then using cbind to add my column, without good results.

Below is what I'm trying to achieve in a new dataframe.

```
Metric                         Values       Line  
Profit before tax               240          5
Earnings per share              0.240        1
EBITDA Margin                   37%          3
```

Thanks

Comment: Split with the last whitespaces? `str_split(df$Metric, "\\s+(?!\\S+\\s)")`?

Comment: And probably you want to split with last whitespaces that are not trailing whitespaces (of course you may use `trimws`, but just in case): `str_split(df$Metric, "\\s+(?=\\S+\\s*$)")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew works perfect, thank you!